# Recurrent neural networks (RNN) and popular recurrence relationships

Tags: rnn

I am looking for a clean problem to study learning process of a RNN. I am thinking of using some number sequences that appear in mathematics and physics, like Fibonacci's, recurrence relations between coefficients of orthogonal polynomials (like Laguerre, Hermite, Legendre,...), etc. The statement of the problem will be something like: I will present to you a sequence of any length with some blanks and then you must teach your RNN until it succeed in getting accuracy 1 for predicting the blacks (it may be the last element of the some sequence like 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, __). This could be useful to connect the complexity of the architecture of the RNN, the learning process, the way to present the information, etc, with the complexity of the true recurrence relation.

Someone knows a problem/project related to this ideas or have some suggestion for how to proceed with the analysis?